# Retro Diels–Alder reaction in synthesis of corallopyronin A

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, pericyclic

I was looking at the synthesis of corallopyronin A in the following paper by Rentsch and Kalesse: [*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2012,** *51* (45), 11381–11384](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201206560).

There is one reaction which is described as

> oxidation and a retro Diels–Alder reaction generated pyrone

[image]

I understand that the DMP oxidises the secondary alcohol to a ketone, and at the end there is an intramolecular esterification to produce the lactone, but I don't quite understand how the retro Diels–Alder reaction works. Could someone explain the reaction steps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my assessment of the mechanism. You are correct about the Dess-Martin periodinane (DMP) oxidation of **1** to **2**. The resulting ketone **2** can also exist as the enols (*E*)-**3** and (*Z*)-**4**. Any one of the three can undergo a retro-Diels-Alder-like thermolysis, but I have chosen (*Z*)-**4** for the convenience of cyclizing ketene **5**, which has lost acetone in the thermolysis. Finally, the ketene **5** affords pyranone **6**.
**ADDENDUM:** Citation for the "*retro*-Diels-Alder". A. R. Katritzky, Z. Wang, M. Wang, C. D. Hall and K. Suzuki, *J. Org. Chem.* **2005**, *70*, 4854. https://doi.org/10.1021/jo050307m

[image]